# Download and save image from HTML source

Tags: c#, asp.net

In our application, based on some input data, an image will be rendered. The images are some charts. As part of our test automation I need to download those charts.

I just have image source url. How can I download the image from the source and save it to disk.

I tried of using different methods and able to download the file. But when I try to open the file, getting a message saying 'not a valid bitmap file,or its format currently not supported.'

Here is my html

```
<div id="chart">
    <img id="c_12" src="Bonus/ModelChartImage?keys%5B0%5D=UKIrelandEBIT&values%5B0%5D=100&privacyModeServer=False&modelId=Bonus" alt="" usemap="#c_12ImageMap" style="height:300px;width:450px;border-width:0px;" />
<map name="c_12ImageMap" id="c_12ImageMap">

    <area shape="rect" coords="255,265,357,266" class="area-map-section" share="Core Bonus" alt="" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="128,43,229,265" class="area-map-section" share="Core Bonus" alt="" />
</map>    
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932390/how-do-i-save-an-image-from-an-url?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. We have to set the cookie container from the web site to your request.

```
public static Stream DownloadImageData(CookieContainer cookies, string siteURL)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = null;
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;

    httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteURL);

    httpRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
    httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

    try
    {
        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var httpContentData = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

            return httpContentData;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (httpResponse != null)
        {
            httpResponse.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to download image from web site (WebClient class, HttpWebRequest, HttpClient class, btw among them new [HttpClient](http://nuget.org/packages/HttpClient) is easiest way).

Here is example with class HttpClient:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
Task<Stream> streamAsync = httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://www.simedarby.com.au/images/SD.Corp.3D.4C.Pos.jpg");

Stream result = streamAsync.Result;
using (Stream fileStream = File.Create("downloaded.jpg"))
{
    result.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: I tried of using different methods and able to download the file. But when I try to open the file, getting a message saying 'not a valid bitmap file,or its format currently not supported.'

Comment: Check that you actually downloaded image. Could be wrong extension or instead of image inside of file HTML or because of "bug" to binary was added some small string. So check downloaded file first of all.

Comment: Website is working on forms based authentication. In that case if I try to download the file from another application, how can I make my request as a authenticated request.

Comment: Watin seems dead.